# Highlight area in Eclipse viewpart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wish to have an area of a viewpart in eclipse highlight when the user selects a link on the viewpart. Sort of a way to draw their attention to this area. My view consists of a few composites with different labels and links in them. I wish to highlight an entire composite. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color of the composite that you wish to highlight...

```
composite.setBackground( SWT.COLOR_YELLOW )
```

Comment: Thank you that worked with some modification, but I did have to add composite.update() in order for the update to occur immediately. Also the composite.setBackground(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW) would not work. I had to change it to composite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));